# Odd loop does not work using %c

Tags: c, scanf

I am leaning C programming. I have written an odd loop but doesn't work while I use `%c` in `scanf()`.
Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char another='y';
    int num;
    while ( another =='y')
    {
        printf("Enter a number:\t");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printf("Sqare of %d is : %d", num, num * num);
        printf("\nWant to enter another number? y/n");
        scanf("%c", &another);
    }
}
```

But if I use `%s` in this code, for example `scanf("%s", &another);`, then it works fine.
Why does this happen? Any idea?

Comment: When You enter the `num` and press ENTER, so the ascii code of ENTER is stored in scanf buffer, and whenever you read next single character, it will not wait for user input and `ENTER` ascii code will be stored in `another` variable.

Answer (score 10):

The `%c` conversion reads the next single character from input, regardless of what it is. In this case, you've previously read a number using `%d`. You had to hit the enter key for that number to be read, *but* you haven't done anything to read the new-line from the input stream.  Therefore, when you do the `%c` conversion, it reads that new-line from the input stream (without waiting for you to actually enter anything, since there's already input waiting to be read).

When you use `%s`, it skips across any leading white-space to get some character other than white-space. It treats a new-line as white-space, so it implicitly skips across that waiting new-line. Since there's (presumably) nothing else waiting to be read, it proceeds to wait for you to enter something, as you apparently desire.

If you want to use `%c` for the conversion, you could precede it with a space in the format string, which will also skip across any white-space in the stream.

Answer (score 2):

The ENTER key is lying in the stdin stream, after you enter a number for first scanf %d. This key gets captured by the scanf %c line.

use `scanf("%1s",char_array); another=char_array[0];`.

Comment: -1 for recommending [undefined behavior](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html).

Answer (score 1):

use `getch()` instead of `scanf()` in this case. Because scanf() expects '\n' but you are accepting only one char at that scanf(). so '\n' given to next scanf() causing confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
char another='y';
int num;
while ( another =='y')
{
    printf("Enter a number:\t");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Sqare of %d is : %d", num, num * num);
    printf("\nWant to enter another number? y/n");
    getchar();
    scanf("%c", &another);
}
}
```