# Getting Debug Error in C

Tags: c

i am a learner of 'C' and written a code, but after i compile it, shows a **Debug Error** message, here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int n,i=1;
    char c;
    printf("Enter Charecter:\t");
    scanf("%s",&c);
    printf("Repeat Time\t");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    n=n;
    while (i <= n)
    {
        printf("%c",c);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Pls tell me why this happens and how to solve it

Comment: Can you show us the actual error message?

Comment: `n=n;` -- what is this intended to do?

Comment: you have `main`-function not compatible with standard

Comment: @Almo here is the screenshot http://i.stack.imgur.com/H79IX.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you understood the answer to your other question: [Odd loop does not work using %c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814128/odd-loop-does-not-work-using-c)

These [format specifiers](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output) are each used for a specific job.

If you want to get a:

- character from `stdin` use `%c`.
- string (a bunch of characters) use `%s`.
- integer use `%d`.

This code:

```
char c;
printf("Enter Character:\t");
scanf("%c",&c);
```

Will read 1 character from `stdin` and will leave a newline (`'\n'`) character there. So let's say the user entered the letter `A` in the `stdin` buffer you have:

```
A\n
```

The `scanf()` will pull `'A'` and store it in your `char c` and will leave the newline character. Next it will ask for your int and the user might input `5`. `stdin` now has:

```
\n5
```

The `scanf()` will take `5` and place it in `int n`. If you want to consume that '\n' there are a number of options, one would be:

```
char c;
printf("Enter Character:\t");
scanf("%c",&c);  // This gets the 'A' and stores it in c
getchar();       // This gets the \n and trashes it
```

Comment: @JessicaLingmn - Happy to help, the newline character seems to trip a lot of people up

Answer (score 3):

`scanf("%s",&c);` should be `scanf("%c",&c);`

The `%s` format specifier tells `scanf` you're passing a char array.  You're passing a single char so need to use `%c` instead.

Your current code will behave unpredictably because `scanf` will try to write an arbitrarily long word followed by a nul terminator to the address you provided.  This address has memory allocated (on the stack) for a single char so you end up over-writing memory that may be used by other parts of your program (say for other local variables).

Comment: Thanks for the concepts helps lot :)

Answer (score 3):

The `scanf("%s", &c)` is writing to memory it should not as `c` is a single `char` but `"%s"` expects its argument to be an array. As `scanf()` appends a null character it will at the very least write two `char` to `c` (the `char` read from `stdin` plus the null terminator), which is one too many.

Use a `char[]` and restrict the number of `char` written by `scanf()`:

```
char data[10];
scanf("%9s", data);
```

and use `printf("%s", data);` instead of `%c` or use `"%c"` as the format specifier in `scanf()`.

Always check the return value of [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), which is the number of successful assignments, to ensure subsequent code is not processing stale or uninitialized variables:

```
if (1 == scanf("%d", &n))
{
    /* 'n' assigned. 'n = n;' is unrequired. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of your code. Please see inline comments in code for fixes:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int n,i=1;
    char c;
    printf("Enter Character:\t");
    scanf("%c",&c);//Use %c instead of %s
    printf("Repeat Time\t");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    n=n;//SUGGESTION:This line is not necessary. When you do scanf on 'n' you store the value in 'n'
    while (i <= n)//COMMENT:Appears you want to print the same character n times?
    {
        printf("%c",c);
        i++;
    }
    return;//Just a good practice
}
```

Comment: 1) void main is extremely *BAD* practice. 
2) If the I/O is buffered (which it likely will be), you won't see the output from printf when the scanf is done
3) The n=n assignment is utterly pointless.

Comment: ya i want to print the same character n times... thanks makes me sense :)

Comment: @Tom Tanner: 1)Agreed. gcc normally wouldn't allow such code. But, since its unknown which compiler OP is using, its best to keep the code intact. 2)Depends on the buffered mechanism. But, the code is valid C and will most certainly work as expected. 3)I have suggested that to the OP as an inline comment in comment.